# angular RXJS how to cast subscribe response type

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

I wrote the backend so I know precisely that format of the data (DTO) that is being returned from my controller.
When I perform a post like:

```
await this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', dto).subscribe(
  (response) => {
```

if try to specify  response: UserDto  for example, I get an error:

[image]

I have also tried casting response to another variable of type UserDto, but that fails as well.  I can't remember having this problem before (like earlier Angular versions??).

This has to be simple - my apologies for not understanding how to do it.
fyi: ng version 12.1.1

Thanks in advance.
Chuck

Comment: You could use the generic post. `this.http.post<UserDto>(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', dto)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the non generic form of the `post` method you'll get a response type of `Observable<HttpResponse>`.  So unless you pipe and map the response yourself, the response in your subscribe will be of type `HttpResponse` so you would have to get the body from the `HttpResponse`.

```
this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', dto).subscribe(
  (response: HttpResponse) => {
    const userDto: UserDto = response.body as UserDto
  }
);
```

Alternatively you could use the generic form of the `post` method which will take in a type to map to...

```
this.http.post<UserDto>(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', dto).subscribe(
  (response: UserDto) => {
    // The response is already map and typed to your UserDto.
  }
);
```

> https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse

> https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post

Answer (score 1):

`subscribe()` method returns an instance of RxJS `Subscription` object which you cannot await. You can await only Promises so you need to convert Observable into a Promise:

```
await response = await this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', dto).toPromise();
```

Note, that in RxJS 8 `toPromise()` will be replaced by two methods `firstValueFrom()` and `lastValueFrom()`.